# Running a Script on Build (e.g. Gulp or Grunt)

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I have a project.json script for 'prepare' that runs a gulpfile to push my bower stuff into the wwwroot. Works great, except during dev I have to manually run it after I update the bower.json package. Any way to automate this during dev? I'd normally use a post-build script but they are no where to be seen. My project.json scripts are looks like this:

```
  "scripts": {
    "prepare": [ "gulp bower" ]
  }
```

What i'd love is:

```
  "scripts": {
    "post-build": [ "gulp bower" ]
  }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `Task Runner Explorer` to automate this. (Use the `Quick Launch` in the upper right, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>, or `View`->`Other Windows`->`Task Runner Explorer`.)

Find the task you want to add (`bower` or `prepare`, depending on the route you want to go), right click, and use the context menu to add the bindings.

My `gruntfile.js`, for example, got the following line added to the top:

```
/// <binding BeforeBuild='beforeBuild' AfterBuild='afterBuildMinimal' ProjectOpened='watch' />
```

I'm not certain if the `gulpfile.js` uses the exact same conventions, but the `Task Runner Explorer` is the way to go, either way!

Comment: *bows* Glad to be of service, Shawn!

Comment: That's right, @JuanDavid. The Task Runner Explorer is only a Visual Studio IDE thing. Now, you'll want to do something completely different, since the project.json is obsolete; I run commands in csproj like this: `<Target Name="PreBuild" BeforeTargets="PreBuildEvent"><Exec Command="cd $(ProjectDir)&#xD;&#xA;gulp bower" /></Target>`

Comment: I use `npx` to avoid installing packages globally: `<Exec Command="npx gulp js" />`

Answer (score 1):

there's postrestore and postbuild you can use on project.json.

I use it like this :

```
"postrestore": [ "npm install", "bower install" ]
"postbuild": [ "brunch build" ]
```

in your example, I think you want

```
"postbuild": [ "gulp bower" ]
```